# Sorting a list in python without using the built in .sort()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def sortList(myList):
    sortList = []
    while myList:
        Min = myList[0]
        for i in myList:
            if i < Min:
                Min = i
        sortList.append(Min)
    return sortList
```

This function should take mylist and return mylist sorted without the used of .sort(). can anyone help me figure out my error to make this program run?

Comment: welcome to SO! the best person for find the errors for you is your interpreter ! if you found those then share them with us, then we can help you!

Comment: This is going to cause an infinite loop, adding the smallest element in `myList` over and over to `sortList`. As a result, `sortList` is going to keep growing until it fills up main memory, overloads the page file, and doesn't leave enough for you to even kill the program. You're going to end up having to nuke your machine (by which I mean a hard reboot)

Comment: If not using ``.sort()`` is the only condition, you can use ``sorted()``.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you meant to do:

```
def sort(L):
    answer = []
    while L:
        min = L[0]
        minInd = 0
        for i in range(len(L)):
            num = L[i]
            if num < min:
                min = num
                minInd = i
        answer.append(num)
        L.pop(minInd)
    return answer
```

Now, let's start improving on that:

```
def sort(L):
    answer = []
    while L:
        minInd = 0
        min = L[0]
        for i,num in enumerate(L):
            if num<min:
                minInd = i
                min = num
        answer.append(min)
        L.pop(minInd)
    return answer
```

And again:

```
def sort(L):
    answer = []
    while L:
        m = min(L)  # using the built-in `min` function
        L.remove(m)
        answer.append(m)
    return answer
```